# replaceAll in groovy no work for long sentence

Tags: java, string, groovy

I have this paragraph(this is just a random text) which I want to remove the last part of the paragraph. I have tried using `replaceAll` but it only works for shorter sentences, for example, **The virus that causes COVID-19**

but I want to remove: **You can be infected by breathing in the virus if you are within close proximity of someone who has COVID-19, or by touching a contaminated surface and then your eyes, nose or mouth.\n\nMost people who fall sick with COVID-19 will experience mild to moderate symptoms and recover without special treatment.**

" The virus that causes COVID-19 is mainly transmitted through droplets generated when an infected person coughs, sneezes, or exhales. These droplets are too heavy to hang in the air, and quickly fall on floors or surfaces.\n\nYou can be infected by breathing in the virus if you are within close proximity of someone who has COVID-19, or by touching a contaminated surface and then your eyes, nose or mouth.\n\nMost people who fall sick with COVID-19 will experience mild to moderate symptoms and recover without special treatment."

```
  String comment = "The virus that causes COVID-19 is mainly transmitted through droplets generated when an infected person coughs, sneezes, or exhales. These droplets are too heavy to hang in the air, and quickly fall on floors or surfaces.\n\nAlso, SOS stands for Style Or Service and we?re here to help you with all your shopping needs. Feel free to contact us at 1.877.765.3009 or e-mail us at sos@solesociety.com. #mysolesociety Have a great day! Feel free to contact us at 855-435-5050 or customerservice@vincecamuto.com if you have any further questions or concerns. Have a great day!"

//produces the right result.
println(comment.replaceAll("Also, SOS stands", " "))
```

```
//this does not produce the right result, instead it prints the entire paragraph with this part included.
println(comment.replaceAll("Also, SOS stands for Style Or Service and we?re here to help you with all your shopping needs. Feel free to contact us at 1.877.765.3009 or e-mail us at sos@solesociety.com. #mysolesociety Have a great day! Feel free to contact us at 855-435-5050 or customerservice@vincecamuto.com if you have any further questions or concerns. Have a great day!", " "))
```

Please help with suggestions on how to go about this

Comment: Consider posting your code. Maybe problem isn't with `replaceAll` but with something else. For instance in Java when we invoke `"foo1"+"foo2".replaceAll("o","x")` we will NOT get as result `fxx1fxx2` but `foo1fxx2`. It happens because `.` operator (used to access members, here `replaceAll` method) has higher priority than `+` (concatenation operator) so `replaceAll` will be invoked only on `"foo2"`. To solve such problem we would need to use parenthesis like `("foo1"+"foo2").replaceAll(..)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added a code snippet to better explain the error.

Comment: Please be aware that `replaceAll` uses a regular expression, and your expression contains - for example - `?` which in a regular expression means that the preceding character is optional, so `we?re` from your expression will not match the `we?re` from the text.

Comment: If your goal is to replace literal text and not regular expressions where characters like `+` `?` etc. has special meaning then use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. Both methods replace *all* occurrences of specified target but `replaceAll` uses regex syntax while `replace` treats target literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `?` has a special meaning in regular expressions. 
When you want to include it literally, you have to mask it.

For example by using `\\?` instead of `?`.

Or by surrounding the whole string by `\\Q` and `\\E`, which means to quote the string (i. E. `"\\Qstring with question marks? This works?\\E"`.

Another solution would be to use `Pattern.quote(pattern)` which is safer as it masks everything, including `\\Q` and `\\E`.

If you do not need regular expressions for pattern matching, it would be best to use `comment.replace(target, replacement)`. This is faster than using a regex.

Have a look at the javadoc!

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.

Comment: OR in case where text itself will contain `\Q` `\E` use result of `Pattern.quote(text)` which will generate regex *representing* passed `text`.